# How to correct MLFlow UI FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]?

Tags: python, machine-learning, command-line, mlflow

I created an MLFlow tracking folder and logged metrics/parameters in the following way:

```
dir_parent = os.getcwd()
dir_mlflow = 'file:' + os.sep + os.path.join(dir_parent, 'mlflow_test')
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(dir_mlflow)

# log parameters in mlflow
mlflow.log_param('batch_size',args.batch_size)
mlflow.log_param('epochs',args.epochs)
mlflow.log_param('learning_rate',args.learning_rate)

# set up a callback function to track model results in training
class LogMetricsCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        mlflow.log_metric('training_loss', logs['loss'], epoch)
        mlflow.log_metric('training_accuracy', logs['accuracy'], epoch)

# get test metrics
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
mlflow.log_metric('test_loss', test_loss)
mlflow.log_metric('test_accuracy', test_acc)

# save model to mlflow
mlflow.keras.log_model(model, artifact_path = 'keras-model')
```

This creates a folder named `mlflow_test` which houses 3 folders: `.trash`, `0`, and `mlruns`

How do I read and interact with the contents of this folder? How do I see my runs?

I tried navigating to the folder from the command line and using both the `mlflow ui` and `mlflow ui --host 0.0.0.0` commands but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\PJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\mlflow\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "C:\Users\PJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\PJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\PJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\PJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\mlflow\cli.py", line 399, in server
    _run_server(
  File "C:\Users\PJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\mlflow\server\__init__.py", line 161, in _run_server
    _exec_cmd(full_command, extra_env=env_map, capture_output=False)
  File "C:\Users\PJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\mlflow\utils\process.py", line 95, in _exec_cmd
    process = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

MLFlow version: 2.1.1

Python version: 3.9.5 64bit

Windows 10 OS

Comment: This error is because of using `mlflow` in Windows and the lack of some `dll`s I guess. (It's not about `tracking_uri`) I think it's better to change the name of the question. Also, try using lower versions of `mlflow` (like release 1.30).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the title. Will try previous versions of MLFlow.

Comment: Tested versions `2.0.1` (same error) and `1.30.0` which it seems doesn't take the `mlflow ui` command (`No module named mlflow.__main__; 'mlflow' is a package and cannot be directly executed`)